# Inline C output value store on rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using inline C to get some output. What I am trying to do is execute the inline C code and render its output to rails view via controller.
The code snippet for inline C is:

```
class Something
  inline(:C) do |builder|
    builder.c 'int test1() {
     char array[20] = "-------Hello from Ruby!------\n";
     printf("%s", array);
     return array;
     }'
   end
end
```

Object is created in the controller of the rails application this way.

```
def index
    something = Something.new
    @something = something.test1
end
```

Now, when I try to store output value of the inline C, it just is not applicable while the output is displayed on the rails log(not on the log file). I am sure that the value displayed is via `return array;` of the `Something` class.
  The index method has `@something` instance set which just stores some value like 4421355280 , but not the value. ie `"-------Hello from Ruby!------"`
I have an index to render the corresponding controller action.

```
<h1>Travel</h1>
<h3><%= @something %></h3>
```

How can I possibly store output value `"-------Hello from Ruby!------"` into `@something?`
[Output of inline C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNeqs.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, its seems that I had some problem on return type on C code. It should have been:

```
 class Something
   inline(:C) do |builder|
     builder.c 'char * test1() {
     char array[20] = "-------Hello from Ruby!------\n";
     printf("%s", array);
     return array;
     }'
   end
 end
```